# Can I change word font color using python?

Tags: python, docxtpl

I am using docxtpl to dealing with word template.
Using RichText can change the new add font, but I want to change font color that exist in word template.
Is there any solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font to your desired color directly to the expression in your template document.

So, say the expression you want to render in color is `{{website}}` and the value is 'stack overflow' you can set the font of the expression in the Word Template: [image]

And in your code create the `context` and `render` it:

```
template = DocxTemplate(path_to_template)
context = {'website':"stack overflow"}
template.render(context)
template.save(path_to_output_file)
```

And the output is in color:
[image]